# How to update kotlin compiler embedable?

Tags: kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have common library with own libraries and build tools for gradle. Like SDK. I updated kotlin to 1.2.71. All ok. I also updated kotlin dsl to newest RC release(no effect).

Then I have projects, which are using this mine SDK. Problem ocurred, when I switched to version 1.2.71 on those projects, because "BuildUtilKt.makeModuleFile" was removed.

> Unable to find method 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.BuildUtilKt.makeModuleFile(Ljava/lang/String;ZLjava/io/File;Ljava/lang/Iterable;Ljava/lang/Iterable;Ljava/lang/Iterable;Ljava/lang/Iterable;Ljava/lang/Iterable;)Ljava/io/File;'.

or

> Unable to find method 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.arguments.K2JSCompilerArguments.setCommonSources([Ljava/lang/String;)V'.

I know how to remove dependencies, when I have it in compile, but I don't know where from I am getting "kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.2.41"

Tried:
 - compileOnly("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.2.71") in buildSrc
 - runtime "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.2.71"

it doesn't work.

Here are printed dependencies: [gist](https://gist.github.com/hanibalsk/f9019f1c0343fb984c5272192ed6862e)

Comment: https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/issues/1207